# Naming layers and methods with same names

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I feel bit of problem while starting naming layers and methods directly as it is happen in below example.

UserRepository, UserService, UserController

and methods

GetUserById, GetUserById and again same name on controller.

Why i am duplicating them re-again ? and just wrap same methods between layers ?

Answer (score 1):

That is what you get when you have a tiered architecture. Having a suffix improves the readability of your code because it gives a clear indication as to which tier this class belongs to.

In addition for the method that you have listed the benefits may not be evident as this happens to be a simple getter. However, for complex business methods that really "do stuff" behind the scenes importance of each layer would be realized.

For example, a use case of "Register User" would have different responsibilities for each layer. The controller might do some validations like whether email is correct, the user name/password has valid syntax, the service layer might send a confirmation email on top of ofcourse checking whether user is unique or not and repository might persist it to some place if everything else is ok.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a sign of poor design. Every layer has to talk it's own "language" with its clients. And this language has to be object-oriented. The "ID-notation" is something outside of the OOP world (and belongs to C-world).

Try to avoid IDs and let objects talk to each other. When it's done your methods will be renamed to something more object oriented.